# React Router with Suspense Lazy Load page always show my notFound page under all my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a component that creates the dynamic routes with a `routes[]` list, but when I add the route for "not found" `NotFoundUrl` page it always shows it to me in all components.

The other routes always work fine but when adding the route for 404 this page is always rendered on top of the others and the idea is that if a route does not exist in the previously added ones, it will render only the `NotFoundUrl` page.

ruotes.tsx

```js
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'admin',
    icon: 'icon-signal',
    component: MyHomePage,
    layout: '/admin',
    text: 'Wellness',
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'admin',
    icon: 'icon-profile',
    component: ProfilePage,
    layout: '/admin',
    text: 'Profile',
  },
  {
    path: '/support',
    name: 'support',
    icon: 'default',
    component: LandingPage,
    layout: '/',
    text: 'Support',
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'notfound',
    icon: '',
    component: NotFoundUrl,
    layout: '/admin',
    text: 'Notfound',
  },
]
```

AdminLayout.tsx

```js
return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="adminContainer">
      <Switch>
        <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
          {routes.map((route, i) => {
            if (route.layout === '/admin') {
              return (
                <Route
                  path={route.layout + route.path}
                  component={route.component}
                  key={i}
                  exact
                />
              );
            }
          })}
        </Suspense>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

My app.tsx:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout />} />
      <Route path="/auth" render={(props) => <AuthLayout />} />
      <Route path="/soporte" render={(props) => <LandingPage />} />
      <Route path="/pago-movil" render={(props) => <GoToApp />} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/auth/login" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried changing the route in various ways but the problem persists.

I tried this:

```
{
  path: '/*',
  name: 'notfound',
  icon: '',
  component: NotFoundUrl,
  layout: '/admin',
  text: 'Notfound',
}
```

Also adding this in the `Switch` component

```
<Route path="/admin/*" component={NotFoundUrl} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Switch` component ***exclusively*** returns the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component, but since the `Switch` is only rendering a `React.Suspense` component it "matches" and renders that instead, and then all routes inside `Suspense` are ***inclusively*** matched and rendered just as if they are in a router.

Move the `Switch` component *inside* the `Suspense` so it can exclusively match and render routes again.

Example:

```
return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="adminContainer">
      <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
        <Switch>
          {routes
            .filter(route => route.layout === '/admin')
            .map((route) => (
              <Route
                key={route.layout + route.path}
                path={route.layout + route.path}
                component={route.component}
                exact
              />
            ))
          }
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```